# Short if condition & for loop in django template

Tags: python, django

How can I list all of telephone numbers in **td** assigned to a given person with a foreign key in one-line statement?

`telefony_list`, `osoby_list` and `email_list` contains all objects pushed from generic ListView.

```
<tbody>
    {% for osoba in osoby_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{osoba.id}}</td>
        <td>{{osoba.imie}}</td>
        <td>{{osoba.nazwisko}}</td>
        <td>{% tel.telefon for tel in telefony_list if tel.osoba_id == osoba.id %}{% endfor %}{% endif %}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

EDIT:

I just solved this problem with

```
  {% for tel in telefony_list %}
    {% if tel.osoba_id == osoba.id %}
      {{tel.telefon}}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</td>
```

But how can I split **tel.telefon** strings? Now they're linked together with no space and I have to display them that they are under each other in one **td**

Actual: [image: Actual result]

Expected: [image]

My models.py:

```py
from django.db import models

class Osoba(models.Model):
    imie = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    nazwisko = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.imie, self.nazwisko)


class Telefon(models.Model):
    osoba = models.ForeignKey(Osoba, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
    telefon = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.telefon


class Email(models.Model):
    osoba = models.ForeignKey(Osoba, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Can you post your models too?

Comment: Just create method inside Osoba class to return data what you need and use it in your template.

Comment: Your edit just created a O(n^2) algorithm in your template. Do what @pako says, or create a view that returns the data in the format you neeed.  ps: add information to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: @pako Could you guide me how to write this method in my Osoba class? Im newbie in django :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RadosławHryniewicki: first of all - use always english names in your code.

Here is the code that should works:

```
class Osoba(models.Model):
    imie = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    nazwisko = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.imie, self.nazwisko)

    @property
    def phones(self):
        return list(Telefon.objects.filter(osoba=self).values_list('telefon', flat=True))


# use in your template:
#    
# {% autoescape off %}   
# {{ osoba.phones|join:"<br />" }}
# {% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: What's wrong with non-english names? They are latin, after all.

Comment: @Gasanov: it's just easier to everyone to read code with english names. It's just a good practice.

Comment: Indeed, it works but not as it should. Is there an option to split new phones in new line in same html div instead of comma? edit: I've changed to english names

Comment: @RadosławHryniewicki: yes, use autoescape: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Now my modified decorated function ```phones(self)``` return empty list despite of fact that I added phones to person. Function: ```@property
    def phones(self):
        return list(Phone.objects.get(person=self.pk).values_list('phone', flat=True))``` ***in template*** : ```<td id="phone">
                          <div>{% autoescape off %} {{ person.phones|join:"<br />" }}{% endautoescape %}</div>```

Comment: I send a query for person with id=3 ```Phone.objects.get(person=3).values_list('phone', flat=True))``` in python shell and I get response of non empty queryset which is good